# What's the minimal time needed to get the highest possible sum of tiles in 2048?

Tags: 2048-game

I was reading [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/48/9000) question / answers realized that people spend a lot more time playing this game than I thought.

I find it interesting - although you may not - to know what is the minimal time needed to get the maximal sum.

Under reasonable assumptions, the question reduces to: **What is the minimal number of moves needed to end up with the highest sum of tiles?**

(It is still interesting to think about how much time I need to be playing to get the super score! I'm not sure if the game keeps records of times somewhere.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single anawer to this question because the game randomly adds a `2` or `4` tile. But it is possible to give a range.

[This answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/2753/15632) shows the maximum possible score. The sum of all tiles is:

$2^{18}-4=262140$

To reach this result you need a `4` as a new tile at least at 16 specific times:

- first time, when the rest of the board is filled with values from 4 to 65536
- second time, when the rest of the board is filled with values from 4 to 32768 and 131072
- and so in until the last `4`

Let's assume the rest of the new tiles were always a `2`. All values on the board are from the 2 starting tiles (also assumed as `2`) and all added tiles. That means, in this case we have the following number of moves:

$\frac{262140-(2*2)-(16*4)}{2}+16=131052$

If we assume we always get a `4` as new tile and also 2 times `4` as the starting tiles it's even simpler:

$\frac{262140-(2*4)}{4}=65533$

Assuming 1 second per move it‘s between 18.2 and 36.4 hours.

Comment: There is a single answer, because it's a minimal time. Assume the game adds the optimal tile in the optimal location every time, and that the player makes the optimal move.

Answer (score -1):

## 3,932,156 points over 18.2 hours @ 1 move / second

Let's assume 1 move / second and all thanks to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/2048/comments/214njx/highest_possible_score_for_2048_warning_math)

---

This assumes that every tile you spawn is a <kbd>2</kbd>, and the last tile you spawn is a <kbd>4</kbd>.

There are $16$ squares. You'd think that the highest possible number would be $2
^{16} (=65536)$, which would fill up the board, making it impossible to progress. However, if you do manage to spawn a <kbd>4</kbd> tile as your last tile, then you can continue to progress to $2^{17} (=131,072)$.

---

Scoring works like this:

Merging two lower-tier blocks together will give you the score of the higher-tier block (score of $+8$ gained from merging two <kbd>4</kbd>s). For any specific tile score, you have to add up all the scores from the lower tiers.

- Creating a <kbd>2</kbd> tile $= +0$ pts
- Creating a <kbd>4</kbd> tile $= 4 = +4$ pts
- Creating an <kbd>8</kbd> tile $= 8 + (2\times4) = +16$ pts
- Creating a <kbd>16</kbd> tile $= 16 + (2\times8) + (4\times4) = +48$ pts
- Creating a <kbd>32</kbd> tile $ = 32 + (2\times16) + (4\times8) + (8\times4) = +128$ pts ...

Which can be simplified:

- Tile <kbd>$2^1$</kbd>$ = 0 \times 2^1 = 0$ pts
- Tile <kbd>$2^2$</kbd>$ = 1 \times 2^2 = 4$ pts
- Tile <kbd>$2^3$</kbd>$ = 2 \times 2^3 = 16$ pts
- Tile <kbd>$2^4$</kbd>$ = 3 \times 2^4 = 48$ pts

Making tile <kbd>$2^n$</kbd>$ = (n-1)2^n$ points.

Making the max tile <kbd>$2^{17}$</kbd>$ = 16 \times 2^{17} = 2,097,152$ points. You would need to spawn 65,536 <kbd>2</kbd> tiles to make a single <kbd>131,072</kbd> tile, which, at 1 legal move per second, would take 18.2 hours.

---

That's only making the max tile.  Now we still need to fill the rest of the board. (Note: combining times are correct, as when you merge two tiles together, you spawn a <kbd>2</kbd> at the same time)

- Next tile <kbd>$2^{16}$</kbd>$ = 983,040$ points ($2^{15}$ tiles or $9.1$ hours)
- <kbd>$2^{15}$</kbd>$ = 458,752$ points ($2^{14}$ tiles or $4.55$ hours)
- <kbd>$2^{14}$</kbd>$ = 212,992$ points ($2^{13}$ tiles or $2.27$ hours)
- <kbd>$2^{13}$</kbd>$ = 98,304$ points ($2^{12}$ tiles or $1.13$ hours)
- <kbd>$2^{12}$</kbd>$ = 45,056$ points ($2^{11}$ tiles or $34$ minutes)
- <kbd>$2^{11}$</kbd>$ = 20,480$ points ($2^{10}$ tiles or $17$ minutes)
- <kbd>$2^{10}$</kbd>$ = 9216$ points ($512$ tiles or $8.5$ minutes)
- <kbd>$512$</kbd>$ = 4096$ points ($256$ tiles or $4.3$ minutes)
- <kbd>$256$</kbd>$ = 1792$ points ($128$ tiles or $2.1$ minutes)
- <kbd>$128$</kbd>$ = 768$ points ($64$ tiles or $64$ seconds)
- <kbd>$64$</kbd>$ = 320$ points ($32$ tiles or $32$ seconds)
- <kbd>$32$</kbd>$ = 128$ points ($16$ tiles or $16$ seconds)
- <kbd>$16$</kbd>$ = 48$ points ($8$ tiles or $8$ seconds)
- <kbd>$8$</kbd>$ = 12$ points ($3$ tiles or $3$ seconds)(This space will be created by two <kbd>2</kbd> tiles, and the last <kbd>4</kbd> tile, so $-4$ points from the equation)

This fills up 15 of the 16 spaces on the board. We don't include the last tile, as it cannot merge with the <kbd>8</kbd>.

---

> **Max points possible: $3,932,156$.**
>   **Max tiles spawned: $131,070$ ($+1$ for last tile, $-1$ for the <kbd>4</kbd>)**
>   **Around 36.4 hours @ 1 move per second.**

If you happen to miss out on the last <kbd>4</kbd> tile, your max score would be $1,835,008$, with $65,535$ ($+1$ for last tile) <kbd>2</kbd> tiles spawned, and $18.2$ hours @ 1 move per second.

Comment: This is going for highest score, not minimal moves to get the highest possible tile sum. Also, it has at least one mathematical error, pointed out in the Reddit comments.