# Maximum tile possible in a game if 2048 on an nXn grid

Tags: mathematics, 2048-game

Playing on an $ n \times n $ grid, how can we determine the largest possible title you can achieve in a game, assuming the computer places tiles in the perfect spots.

Comment: There's a [very similar question already posted](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48/what-is-the-largest-tile-possible-in-2048?rq=1), though the answers there have a lot of holes.

Comment: Looks like there's an answer in [this Mathematics SE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716469/maximum-board-position-in-2048-game).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $2^{n^2+1}$. This is because $n^2$ is the number of squares in an $n\times n$ grid, and the $+1$ comes from requiring that the last square spawned be a $4 = 2^2$.

Comment: Can you prove there's a sequence of tile spawns and moves that leads to this tile's creation?

Comment: It's easy to see that in order to form a square of value $2^{m+1}$, having already a square of value $2^m$, you will need to fill $m$ squares ($m \geq 2$); of course, this assumes perfect conditions. For instance, in order to form a square of value $8$, having already a square of value $4$, you will need two $4$'s, for a total of two squares. In order to to form a square of value $16$, having already a square of value $8$, you will need two $4$'s and one $8$, for a total of three squares. This goes on, and the maximum number of squares you can use is $n^2$.

Comment: That only argues that it's impossible to create a bigger tile. Can you prove creating a tile of value $2^{n^2+1}$ is actually possible?

Comment: Use the strategy described above, with base case a square $4$ spawned in a corner and going row by row in a zig-zag fashion.

Comment: Tiles will spawn while you're doing that and mess you up.

Comment: 'perfect spots'

Comment: Seriously, say you're merging 4+4+8+16+32+64+128 to produce 256. 6 tiles will spawn while you're doing that. How do you prove that you can place the spawns and perform the merges in such a way that once you have your 256, the rest of the board state isn't completely screwed up?

Comment: To produce $2^{n+2}$ ($n = 6$ in your example) we will have $n$ tile spawns. We may have these all be $2$ tiles if we wish, so they add up to $2n$, which is much much less than $2^{n+2}$. Even if the spawns were mostly all over the place there is, plenty of room to correct that  with future spawns. We can continue this discussion in chat if you wish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30840/discussion-between-user2357112-and-fimpellizieri).